# Renaming multiple files in python parallely with their checksum (using multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file, multiprocessing

I have written the following code that renames files in a directory (with their `SHA3-512` checksum):

```py
import hashlib
import os

base_dir = './data'

def calc_checksum(file_name):
    with open(file=os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        return str(hashlib.sha3_512(f.read().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[0:32])
    
def rename_file(file_name):
        extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]
        os.rename(os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), os.path.join(base_dir, calc_checksum(file_name) + '.' + extension))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file_name in os.listdir(base_dir):
        rename_file(file_name)
```

This code works fine for my purpose - but it is single-threaded. I'm trying to make this operation parallel since the name of one file (derived from its checksum) is independent of all other files in the directory.

I've made the following changes to make it run in parallel:

```py
import hashlib
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


base_dir = './data'

def calc_checksum(file_name):
    with open(file=os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        return str(hashlib.sha3_512(f.read().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[0:32])
    
def rename_file(file_name):
        extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]
        os.rename(os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), os.path.join(base_dir, calc_checksum(file_name) + '.' + extension))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        pool.map_async(rename_file, os.listdir(base_dir))
```

However, the script runs and terminates without changing a single file name.

Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works, using `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` package:

```
import hashlib
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

base_dir = './data'

def calc_checksum(file_name):
    with open(file=os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
        return str(hashlib.sha3_512(f.read().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[16:52])
    
def rename_file(file_name):
        extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]
        os.rename(os.path.join(base_dir, file_name), os.path.join(base_dir, calc_checksum(file_name) + '.' + extension))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        executor.map(rename_file, os.listdir(base_dir))
```

Although I'm still not sure why my second solution in the question does not work.